# How can I instrument/intercept Method.invoke in a ByteBuddy agent?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

This doesn't seem to work:

```
new AgentBuilder
  .Default()
  .with(initStrat)
  .ignore(not(is(Method.class)))
  .type(any()).transform(....)
```

Also, I only want to intercept `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` and not other methods of the `Method` class.

Also where in the code can I see the list of classes, packages, and modules that are ignored by default?

Answer (score 0):

This seems about right but instrumenting classes on the boot class is specially tricky since your agent will not be visible to such classes. In the transformer add your instrumentation and restrict it to the `invoke` method by an appropriate matcher.

Add a `AgentBuilder.Listener` to get notifications on all classes that are instrumented by Byte Buddy.